# How to check even count of "1" in binary representation of number?

Tags: java

I have integer. How to check that this integer has odd or even number of 1 in binary representation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Integer.bitCount(int i)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount%28int%29).